# sum records and rest gradually query

Tags: mysql

I have this question, I sum records with common field name

```
name         quantity   lot
product1 -    20   -   lot1
product1 -    10   -   lot2
product1 -     7   -   lot3

total         37
```

In my form show this value and the user rest to the total quantity, how do make a query to rest gradually eacth record.

This is possible in mysql?.

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the running sum?

Comment: Okay, let me see if I understand this: You want to get a total sum of each product based on the product name, and then you want to show the sort of running total for each row as it goes? I believe you can do this with MySQL and a bit of PHP (assuming you're using PHP) script.